# Best way to check legitimate double entered into HTML box?

Tags: html, double

This the code I have right now:

```
<p align="center">Please enter a bid (in double format, without a $): <input type="double" name="bid" value="0.00"></p>
```

I have "double" set as the input type, but when I type in a string it appears to automatically convert it to a double which does not serve my purposes...

What is the best way to enforce this? Thank you.

EDIT: Thanks for letting me know that double is not a type. However, I can't use "number" because I want to enter monetary values and need the decimal points.

Comment: What is `type="double"`?

Comment: A little javascript onblur event processing? I'd use jQuery "change"

Comment: There is no input type=double. Change that to type=number
See http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/input.number.html

If you want a string, use type=text

Comment: Careful with type='number' and mobile OSes!

Comment: @NickM `type="number"` on mobile OSes is the best time to use it!

Comment: `type=number` for floating point input? That is so wrong on so many levels. Oh wait, you say monetary values. That's OK then, `type=number` is perfect for that purpose. Can you show an example, for instance a jsFiddle, where you think it doesn't work?